# WPF binding not worked for foreground property in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I have following code to set the foreground property

`TextBlock label = new TextBlock() { Style = LabelStyle };
    Binding binding = new Binding(LabelColor) { Source = dataContextProperty };
    label.SetBinding(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, binding);`

Note that LabelColor is a Brush.
If I set,

```
label.SetBinding(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, binding)
```

It worked. So why it is not working only for foreground?

Comment: your code not error? binding should accept string, right? and what is dataContextProperty?

Comment: do you have any explicitly set local value of `Background`?

Comment: @Yuliam Chandra : I think here binding should accept brush. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.foreground(v=vs.100).aspx   dataContextProperty is the source and do you think it is related to the issue?

Comment: @King King : I am not setting `Background` any other places.